# how to sort elements and group them based on unique element or ID, which has namespace

Tags: xslt

i have asked with the same question but not with the namespace

i have an xml like..this

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<FinalDbGetUserId>
  <FinalDbGetUserIdOutputCollection xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/FinalDbGetUserId"
                                    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/FinalDbGetUserId">
    <ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
      <ns0:USER_ID>237</ns0:USER_ID>
      <ns0:BusinessEntity>
        <ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201114</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>
        <ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>207</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>
      </ns0:BusinessEntity>
    </ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
    <ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
      <ns0:USER_ID>237</ns0:USER_ID>
      <ns0:BusinessEntity>
        <ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201119</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>
        <ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>212</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>
      </ns0:BusinessEntity>
    </ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
    <ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
      <ns0:USER_ID>237</ns0:USER_ID>
      <ns0:BusinessEntity>
        <ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201129</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>
        <ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>230</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>
      </ns0:BusinessEntity>
    </ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
  </FinalDbGetUserIdOutputCollection>
</FinalDbGetUserId>
```

output should be like

```
<FinalDbGetUserId>
  <FinalDbGetUserIdOutputCollection xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/FinalDbGetUserId"
                                    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/FinalDbGetUserId">
    <ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
      <ns0:USER_ID>237</ns0:USER_ID>
      <ns0:BusinessEntity>
        <ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201114</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>
        <ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>207</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>
      </ns0:BusinessEntity>
      <ns0:BusinessEntity>
        <ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201119</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>
        <ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>212</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>
      </ns0:BusinessEntity>
      <ns0:BusinessEntity>
        <ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201129</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>
        <ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>230</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>
      </ns0:BusinessEntity>
    </ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS>
  </FinalDbGetUserIdOutputCollection>
</FinalDbGetUserId>
```

Following is the below xslt, that i was trying and not getting the desired result

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kuserID" match="USERUBSCRIBERS"  use="USER_ID"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
         <xsl:sort select="USER_ID" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match=
 "USERUBSCRIBERS|USER_ID
 |BusinessEntity"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "USERUBSCRIBERS
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kuserID', USER_ID)[1])
     ]">
  <USERUBSCRIBERS>
   <xsl:copy-of select="USER_ID"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="key('kuserID',USER_ID)" />
  </USERUBSCRIBERS>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="USERUBSCRIBERS" mode="copy">
  <BusinessEntity>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </BusinessEntity>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i am getting the output same as input and there is no change.
may be i am doing mistake, but not getting what the mistake is .... trying to find it out

Comment: This is a very basic grouping question, what part of it are you finding difficult? Why do namespaces affect the problem? It's difficult to answer such questions without knowing where your difficulties lie - we don't know how much you know. Someone might just code it up for you, but I tend to avoid that - there's no guarantee that people will understand the code, and if they don't understand it, they tend to come straight back with another question.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers in the previous similar question which reflects best your requirements. That answer will be used to answer this following up.

Answer (score 1):

Define `xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/FinalDbGetUserId"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element, then use the prefix `ns0` anywhere in your stylesheet where you match or select elements from that namespace e.g. `<xsl:key name="kuserID" match="ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS"  use="ns0:USER_ID"/>` and `<xsl:sort select="ns0:USER_ID" data-type="number"/>`.